# Does the unit "volt-seconds" have any interesting interpretation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, units, inductance

I was contemplating the units of capacitance and inductance in electrical circuit theory and noticed something that bugs me. Although there are many equivalent ways to write the farad (seconds per ohm, for instance), the "natural" way it's usually introduced is as coulombs per volt. This is easy to describe within circuit theory -- pumping one coulomb of excess charge onto a one-farad capacitor raises its voltage by one volt.

Inductance, on the other hand, is not so simple. The corresponding "natural" way to define the henry would be as webers per ampere. But circuit theory doesn't include the concept of magnetic flux, which is a bit unsatisfying. If I don't need to (directly) bring up fields to describe capacitance, why should I have to do so for inductance?

Seeking symmetry, I considered other forms of the units:

$$\mathrm{1\ F = 1\ \frac {A \cdot s} V}$$
$$\mathrm{1\ H = 1\ \frac {V \cdot s} A}$$

These are nice and symmetrical and work within circuit theory. But again, I run into an interpretation problem. Amp-seconds make sense on their own -- they're just coulombs, the unit of charge. But what are volt-seconds? Is there any way to interpret them without talking about inductance?

A volt is a joule per coulomb, so maybe joule-seconds mean something? I know that joule-seconds are the units of action and angular momentum. I'm not sure what that gets me.

I see a few different possible explanations for my difficulty interpreting the henry in the context of circuit theory:

1. Inductance is a magnetic phenomenon, and since magnetism has a vector potential, inductance just isn't going to fit neatly into our purely-scalar circuit theory the way that capacitance does.
2. Electrical circuit theory is fundamentally incomplete without [magnetic circuit theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit), which includes magnetic flux as a basic element.
3. Volt-seconds have a meaningful interpretation that doesn't directly involve magnetic fields.

Can anyone tell me what's really going on?

EDIT: Puk and The Photon have clued me in to another possibility:

4. My real mistake is talking about charge independently of capacitance. Kirchhoff's current law says that charge can't accumulate at a node. Maybe that means that talking about charge in a purely resistive circuit doesn't actually make sense, and that in circuit theory the concept of charge is fundamentally tied to capacitance. So I either have to leave out charge and rely solely on $i = C\frac{dv}{dt}$ to describe the behavior of a capacitor, or I have to add *both* charge *and* flux into the picture.

To clarify my motivation: I'm an electrical engineer. When we analyze electrical circuits, we normally only use voltage and current. Our whole reason for using circuit theory is to avoid having to work with fields by solving Maxwell's equations, so we generally don't talk about magnetic flux. My intuition is that, since I'm already using the concept of current, I should be able to freely talk about charge as well, whereas flux is an "outside" concept that has to be added in separately. But as discussed in my #4 above, I'm starting to think that intuition is wrong.

Comment: Yes, here is one. Let $V(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(f)e^{\mathfrak j 2\pi f t}df$ that is $A(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}V(t)e^{-\mathfrak j 2\pi f t}dt$, in other words the $A(f)$ is the Fourier transform of the time function $V(t)$, then if $V(t)$ is measured in $volt$ then $A(f)$ is measured in $volt/Hz$ that is $volt\cdot sec$.

Comment: "But what are volt-seconds? Is there any way to interpret them without talking about inductance?" - Have you considered what the answer might be if magnetic charge exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The volt-second is the [weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_(unit)), the SI unit of [magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux). Applying 1 volt across an ideal inductor for 1 second increases its flux by 1 weber.

Comment: I know that, but I'm hoping for an explanation that doesn't involve magnetism. For instance, if I run one ampere of current through a resistor for one second, I've moved one coulomb of charge through the resistor. If I apply one volt to a resistor for one second, I've done... what, exactly?

Comment: I don't quite understand your objection to inductors or magnetic fields while you accept resistors and capacitors. The inductor is the dual element to the capacitor in circuit theory, just as voltage and current are dual quantities. Flux is to an inductor what charge is to a capacitor. You can convert a circuit with capacitors to its mathematically equivalent dual circuit with inductor, in which case charges become fluxes. Within circuit theory, flux is no less fundamental than charge, and I don't think you'll find a more satisfactory answer if you are looking for an analogue of charge.

Comment: Maybe my question is poorly-formed. I'm not even totally sure what I'm groping towards, here. What bothers me is that I feel like I can talk about charge without reference to capacitors, but I can't talk about flux without reference to inductors. In practice, EEs normally only use voltage and current when analyzing circuits. Maybe talking about charge in a resistive circuit is the mistake. Maybe Kirchhoff's current law means I can't really do that.

Comment: @AdamHaun Unfortunately I'm not aware of a straightforward interpretation without referring to flux. Even though voltage and current are on equal footing mathematically as far as circuit theory is concerned, they differ in physical meaning in that we don't normally view voltage as the flow rate of something, except possibly flux in an inductor.

Answer (score 4):

> circuit theory doesn't include the concept of magnetic flux,

This is absolutely not true. Magnetic flux is one of the four fundamental circuit variables used in circuit theory, as shown in this diagram:

[image]

(source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Two-terminal_non-linear_circuit_elements.svg))

It is the variable that represents the state of an inductor, just as charge is the variable that represents the state of a capacitor.

And there it is by no means a step outside of circuit theory to identify flux as something that is accumulated when voltage is applied to an inductor over time, and thus giving it the unit of volt-seconds is entirely natural within circuit theory.

What circuit theory doesn't account for is the build up of magnetic flux around the ideal wires connecting circuit elements (just as it doesn't account for charge build up in those wires). Which is easily resolved by including parasitic inductors (and parasitic capacitors) within our circuit models when such flux (or charge) is significant.

> Is there any way to interpret them [the unit of volt-seconds] without talking about inductance?

Within circuit theory we can't, but equally we can't interpret charge without talking about capacitance.

> I see a few different possible explanations for my difficulty interpreting the henry in the context of circuit theory: ...
>
> 3. Electrical circuit theory is fundamentally incomplete without magnetic circuit theory, which includes magnetic flux as a basic element.

Circuit theory is incomplete without consideration of the inductor as one of the fundamental circuit elements, and the inductor is a device whose behavior depends on magnetic phenomena.

But I've never heard anyone previously distinguish "electrical circuit theory" from "magnetic circuit theory". Both electrical and magnetic phenomena are considered as part of what most people just call "circuit theory".

Comment: By "magnetic circuit theory" I mean the treatment of magnetic devices like transformers via the concepts of magnetomotive force, magnetic flux, and reluctance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit

I think you are mostly arguing in favor of my #2, then. I'm not sure I agree that we *need* flux and charge to define inductors and capacitors as circuit elements -- $i = C\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $v = L\frac{di}{dt}$ do the job just fine, and voltage and current are enough to describe the state of a capacitor and an inductor, respectively. I am now curious about the history of circuit theory!

Comment: You can certainly talk about charge without capacitance, too -- that's how electrical phenomena are introduced when taught!

Comment: On second thought (having thought about Puk's comment on his answer) maybe you're right. Maybe it doesn't make sense to talk about charge the way I am.

Comment: If you're talking about charge without capacitance, that's electrostatics or electromagnetics, not circuit theory.

Comment: As for writing the constitutive relations for the different circuit elements, consider what if you want them in integral form. Then you need charge to explain the capacitor and flux to explain the inductor. We don't do much with integral equations these days, but they're an equally valid way to solve circuits as differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

You have volts seconds per amp, so it's not "ampere-seconds = Coulomb". It's amps per seconds.

So...you have amps per second (rate of change of current). An inductor gets a voltage across it when there is a non-zero rate of change of current.

So... one Henry means you get one volt per (amp/sec).

No magnetic field needed.